# Conversion of SQL Server datetime column to 24h format failing

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, time

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a `DateTime` column that I'd like to convert into 24h format.

The canonical guidance is to use something along the lines of:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, GetDate(), 121)
```

which yields:

```
2012-01-24 15:22:27.340
```

Perfect. Ok, so applying this knowledge, let's replace `GetDate()` with a column for the `CONVERT` expression:

```
select top(5) CONVERT(datetime, LogTable.Timestamp, 121) from LogTable
order by LogTable.Id DESC
```

And we get:

```
2012-01-24 03:25:47.933
2012-01-24 03:25:46.917
2012-01-24 03:25:46.547
2012-01-24 03:25:46.543
2012-01-24 03:25:46.543
```

What am I doing wrong? How should the expression be crafted to get `CONVERT` to work on a column as opposed to the output of the `GetDate()` function?

Comment: What's wrong, exactly?  Why is your output above unexpected?

Comment: What is the actual data in LogTable.Timestamp?  Is that a VarChar (or nvarchar) column, or is it already a DateTime?

Comment: Are you sure the LogTable.Timestamp data isn't actually 3am?

Comment: Your example shouldn't even compile, you are not selecting from any table. I am surprised that you actually get some data back. \

Comment: The output I was expecting was in 24h format - eg. 3:25p = 15:25h. The field is of type datetime. And yes, the time stamps are actually from a recent capture, so 3pm EST.

Comment: I believe you would have to convert to a **varchar()** to see any effect: `CONVERT(varchar(25), LogTable.Timestamp, 121)`. Right now, you're just converting back to a `DATETIME` and that'll just be displayed in the default system formatting (e.g. in your case: 3pm for 15:00 hours). The `DATETIME` datatype **has NO formatting** in SQL Server - it's stored as two INT values - only **string representations** have any formatting you want

Comment: Good suggestion - although, as per my canonical example, datetime works with the GetDate() function. Unfortunately, same result for me: No 24h times. I am now beginning to suspect that the service which is writing these entries to SQL (captured from a network appliance) isn't distinguishing am/pm...

Comment: @ChrisR.Chapman: well, I would just insert an additional "test" row with `2012-01-24T15:55:55` or something and see if *that* row gets returned properly in 24h format with your various approaches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the resolution to this issue: The service writing timestamps into the SQL table was, through bad formatting, writing "naked" datetimes into the field, effectively making them appear as "AM" irrespective of when they arrived.

I managed to re-write the source code to write 24h datetimes into the field and it is now performing as expected. I am relieved to know my intuition was correct and it was an errant service that was the source.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions and guidance - very, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

24h format only matters for strings.  When you use:

```
convert(datetime, ...
```

You are converting to datetime.  To display 24h, you have to convert to string, like:

```
convert(varchar(24), ...
```

If you start with a varchar column, you can [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it to datetime and back to varchar to display in 24h format.  For example, to convert an AM/PM varchar and display it in 24h:

```
select convert(varchar(16), convert(datetime, 'sep 01 2011 01:23PM', 100), 120)
```

Here, style 100 is used for parsing. Style 120 is used for formatting.

Comment: I understand; however, if 24h format only applies to strings, why does CONVERT(datetime, GetDate(), 121) result in a date with a 24h format?

Comment: Your client is probably configured to display 24h dates.  Does `select getdate()` show a 24h date too?